# Mac OS Extended Journaled vs. NTFS

Tags: osx-lion, macbook-pro

Which of those formats are more reliable to errors for external hard drive, considering that in some rare cases the hard drive may be unplugged without ejecting or some other various cases, where errors may happen. Which one can recover the files and has less corruption rate? HDD will be connected to Lion and do some backup job. For NTFS Paragon NTFS driver is installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NTFS has great file recovery options available, whereas HFS (and other Linux variants) would usually be more involved for data recovery. You would still need to unmount the drive before unplugging it (dragging it to the Trash to eject), no matter what FS you use though

Comment: I thought `journaled` means it is taking up some more space as price of more recovery abilities, comparing to NTFS.

Comment: You question didn't say Journaled when I answered, so I didn't add that. Yes, journaling will help for data corruption due to a power outage or sudden stopage. I do not know, however, if recovery from deleting files or damaged hard drives would affect this